# Vue multiselect not adding new tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a Vue Multiselect instance with 2 functions (one basically hits the database for an autocomplete function, which works. The other is adding a new one that isn't in the database)

So say 'Tag One' is in the database, if I type that and it shows then hitting enter or selecting will save it to the tags (multiselect with tagging enabled). However, if I type 'Tag Three' which isn't in the database and I hit enter or select, it just disappears and doesn't add to the tags or call the axios function in my addTag method.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@johmun/vue-tags-input/dist/vue-tags-input.js"></script>

<div id="tagApp">
  <multiselect
    label="tag_data"
    track-by="campaign_tag_id"
    v-model="value"
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    :taggable="true"
    @tag="addTag"
    @search-change="val => read(val)"
    :preselect-first="false"
    :close-on-select="false" 
    :clear-on-select="true" 
    :preserve-search="true" 
    tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" 
    placeholder="Search or add a tag"
  ></multiselect>
</div>

new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  el: "#tagApp",
  data() {
    return{
        value: [],
        loading: false,
        options: []
    }

  },
  methods: {
    read: function(val){
      if (val) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.options = [];

        const self = this;
        console.log(val);

        axios.get('search',{params: {query: val}})
            .then(function (response) {
                self.options = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
        });

      } else {
        this.options = [];
      }
    },
    addTag(newTag) {
      const tag = {
        tag_data: newTag,
      };
      const campaign_id = document.querySelector("input[name=campaign_id]").value;

      this.options.push(tag);
      this.value.push(tag);

      axios.post('tags/save',{
            tag_data: newTag,
      })
      .then(function (response){
            console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in console? I'm getting ' Cannot read property 'value' of null'.  Actually this line fails `document.querySelector("input[name=campaign_id]")`.

Comment: Sorry @dganenco, I removed the campaign_id code since it isn't needed here.

Comment: Debugging isn't offering anything other than that for ne

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you are doing anything wrong, I just don’t think the component supports what you want to do.

But, what you could do is always add the search term to the options array if it isn’t there already.  Putting the below in the axios callback could be all you need.

```
self.options = response.data;
self.options.push(val)
```

Now you could slice it to the front, or keep it pushed at the end, and code to prevent duplicates etc.